# Android - get application account outside SyncAdapter (handle sync options)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-syncadapter

How to get application account that I create? In my SyncAdapter I have account in `onPerformSync` method, but how I can get the account outside SyncAdapter without adding `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, for ex. in MainActivity?

The target is that I want to handle Sync options from my application, like checking is sync is enable etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission to do whatever you are trying to do. You can get the application account you create by doing something like this:

```
public static Account[] getAccounts(Context context) {
    AccountManager accManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    return accManager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
}
```

Here the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` refers to the type of your account that you create. This will get you back a list of the accounts, if you have multiple ones.

What do you mean by **"handle sync options"**?

But you can use the various static methods of the [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) class to get/set the various attributes for a sync adapter. For example, to check if sync is enabled for your account you can use:

- [ContentResolver.getIsSyncable()](http://goo.gl/AfSCZI)
- [ContentResolver.setIsSyncable()](http://goo.gl/B8UMJ4)